# virsh reporting unknown feature amd-sev-es

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, centos8

I updated my centos and I can no longer start any VM. It says:

```
error: failed to get emulator capabilities
error: internal error: unknown feature amd-sev-es
```

But I'm using a Intel CPU (E5-2678v3) so it can't have AMD features. How can I disable this feature?

Removing /var/cache/libvirt/qemu/capabilities/* doesn't work. "virsh domcapabilities" returns the error above.

Version:

Centos8 stream

libvirt-6.0.0-35.module_el8.5.0+746+bbd5d70c.x86_64

kernel-core-4.18.0-305.el8.x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known bug, see [#1961558](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1961558) and [#1961562](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1961562).

For more detailed workaround around the problem, see each Bugzilla page, but for short, either:

- downgrade `edk2-ovmf` from `edk2-ovmf-20200602gitca407c7246bf-5.el8` to `edk2-ovmf-20200602gitca407c7246bf-4.el8`, or
- run this command:

  ```sh
  mkdir -p /etc/qemu/firmware
  touch /etc/qemu/firmware/50-edk2-ovmf-cc.json
  ```

  in your QEMU host.

Answer (score 1):

To downgrade the pkg:

```
# yum downgrade edk2-ovmf
```